# k8s namspaces always in Terminating

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

Kubernetes is "unable to delete namespace", always in "Terminating" state.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @tmp.json https://kubernetes-cluster-ip/api/v1/namespaces/annoying-namespace-to-delete/finalize.I have tried this method and it has no effect.

Comment: You should edit your original question to include what you've tried rather than leave it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

Replace `{NAMESPACE_NAME}` with namespace name

> kubectl get namespace {NAMESPACE_NAME} -o json >
>   tmp.json

edit `tmp.json` file and remove"`kubernetes`" from

```
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
```

Open new terminal and run command

> kubectl proxy

In another terminal run this command

> curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary
>   @tmp.json
>   https://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/{NAMESPACE_NAME}/finalize

Comment: This is the same code I linked to in my answer and that he claimed didn't work...

Comment: I have clarify the steps while you have added the link which if get expire in future no one will be able to get that answer. while i have added the answer here so that any one in the future can also solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60807

It seems you'll have to try one of the suggested options there or downgrade to an earlier version.

Comment: You provided this issue, I have tried the above solution, still useless

Comment: @liangchengcheng You clearly did not follow the link, as it contains the exact code that you accepted as the answer from Harsh Manvar.

Comment: @EntangledLoops IF you follow the policy of stackoverflow and check it they are suggesting you to write the answer here rather then adding the link as link got expire if it's from third party.

Comment: @HarshManvar Good to know, will do in the future.